# Unable to download signal-desktop on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Please help!

Tags: apt, 20.04, software-installation

So I tried to install Signal-desktop on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS according to the instructions given on the official website of Signal:-

```
# NOTE: These instructions only work for 64 bit Debian-based
# Linux distributions such as Ubuntu, Mint etc.

# 1. Install our official public software signing key
wget -O- https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt/keys.asc | gpg --dearmor > signal-desktop- 
keyring.gpg
sudo mv signal-desktop-keyring.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/

# 2. Add our repository to your list of repositories
echo 'deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/signal-desktop-keyring.gpg] 
https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial main' |\
 sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list

# 3. Update your package database and install signal
sudo apt update && sudo apt install signal-desktop
```

When I ran #1, I got,

```
deep@maharajadhiraja-deep:~$ wget -O- https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt/keys.asc | gpg 
--dearmor > signal-desktop-keyring.gpg
--2021-04-04 20:50:47--  https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt/keys.asc
Resolving updates.signal.org (updates.signal.org)... 2606:4700::6812:1f70, 
2606:4700::6812:1e70, 104.18.31.112, ...
Connecting to updates.signal.org (updates.signal.org)|2606:4700::6812:1f70|:443... 
connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3090 (3.0K) [application/pgp-signature]
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

-                   100%[===================>]   3.02K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2021-04-04 20:50:48 (27.0 MB/s) - written to stdout [3090/3090]
deep@maharajadhiraja-deep:~$ sudo mv signal-desktop-keyring.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/
```

#2

```
deep@maharajadhiraja-deep:~$ echo 'deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/signal- 
desktop-keyring.gpg] https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial main' |  sudo tee -a 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/signal-desktop-keyring.gpg] 
https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial main
```

#3

```
deep@maharajadhiraja-deep:~$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install signal-desktop
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source 
https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt/ xenial: /usr/share/keyrings/signal-desktop- 
keyring.gpg != 
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

And so I'm unable to install Signal-desktop. Moreover,

```
 sudo apt-get <function>
```

is also not working. For example, when I try to run on the terminal:

```
 sudo apt-get upgrade
```

it returns:-

```
 E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source 
 https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt/ xenial: /usr/share/keyrings/signal-desktop- 
 keyring.gpg != 
 E: The list of sources could not be read.
 E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source 
 https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt/ xenial: /usr/share/keyrings/signal-desktop- 
 keyring.gpg != 
 E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I'm clueless as to what is happening out here. Please help me out.

I'm fairly a new user of Ubuntu and I'm trying to figure things out myself. Thank you in advance for attention.

Comment: `signal-desktop` is available in the Ubuntu Software Center which might be your best bet. Did you try that?

Comment: You have a Signal issue, not an Ubuntu issue. Please let Signal Support know that their Linux install instructions are obsolete and result in breakage.

Comment: @24601 I tried just now but I got the message ' Unable to install "Signal ": status-code=409 kind=snap-change-conflict message=snap "signal-desktop" has "install-snap" change in progress '

Comment: @24601 The installation was successful. Thank you. I didn't try but it got installed successfully. But I didn't understand what happened so if you please explain me what happened as I'm clueless as to what happened?

Comment: However I am unable to use   sudo apt-get <function>  . It is still returning the same output as I had mentioned earlier.

Comment: @DEEPBHOWMIK I've added that as an answer if you would care to [accept it](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) Thank you.

Comment: Are you able to install other packages or only having problem with this one?

Comment: @Jdeep Didn't try installing other packages after the installation. But there may be some problems with that as I'm unable to run update or upgrade on the terminal using apt-get. It's returning some errors as I have mentioned earlier and in this question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1329308/sudo-apt-get-function-returns-error-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts).

Comment: @DEEPBHOWMIK , Xenial is btw the code name of Ubuntu 16.04 (which is no longer supported). Tou should try with focal

Comment: @Jdeep Already, I have installed `signal-desktop` by following the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `signal-desktop` from the Ubuntu software Center.

It will be a much cleaner install bringing with it all the additional bits it requires.

[image]

Comment: But the other problem sir? Though I have been able to install `signal-desktop` with the help of your advice, I'm unable to run `sudo apt-get <function>` on the terminal as it keeps on returning the error as I had mentioned above. Sir, if you could please help me with that as well?

Comment: You should raise a new question about that issue with details specific to it. If the `signal-desktop` issue is resolved, you should mark it as such. The site Q/A format requires focus on one question, one answer.

Answer (score 4):

Both problems, installation and running of signal-desktop as well as apt-get functionality returning this error, come from unexpected content in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list`. (In my case this was introduced when trying to install the beta version of signal-desktop).

I would simply remove the apt file in question:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list
```

After that, re-do the steps listed on https://signal.org/de/download/# for installation of signal and things should work.