# sudo apt-get... returns "Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source" error

Tags: apt, 20.04, software-installation, sudo

Yesterday I installed `signal-desktop` on Ubuntu 20.04 and after a lot of problems, I finally was able to install it. The details of the problems are given in the post [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1329200/unable-to-download-signal-desktop-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-please-help)

The reason I'm linking my earlier post here is that my problem now is linked to the previous problems which I faced while installing `signal-desktop`. The problem is that when I run `sudo apt-get <function>` on the terminal where `<function>` stands for `update`, `upgrade`, `autoremove` etc, it is returning errors.

For example:-

```
deep@maharajadhiraja-deep:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for deep:  
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source 
https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt/ xenial: /usr/share/keyrings/signal-desktop- 
keyring.gpg != 
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Another example:-

```
deep@maharajadhiraja-deep:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source 
https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt/ xenial: /usr/share/keyrings/signal-desktop- 
keyring.gpg != 
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source 
https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt/ xenial: /usr/share/keyrings/signal-desktop- 
keyring.gpg != 
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

So, I'm unable to run the commands on my system. Please help me out. And thanks in advance for attention.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can solve the conflict by these commands.

```
sudo rm /usr/share/keyrings/signal-desktop-keyring.gpg

sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain why those commands work?

Comment: @JamesK , Those commands donot fix anything. They just delete the gpg key which did not match with the key in the repository(`/etc/apt../..-xenial.list`) . Because of the wrong public key, `apt-get` was unable to update the package list.