# Error message E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source

Tags: package-management, wine

Revised Question in light of better info collected:
On my Ubuntu 22.04 system

1. when I execute the command:

   ```
   ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d
   ```

   I get the output:

   ```
   unit193-ubuntu-encryption-jammy.list    winehq-jammy.sources  winehq.list.save
   unit193-ubuntu-encryption-jammy.list.save  winehq.list
   ```
2. command:

   ```
   sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
   ```

   output:

   ```
   rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/apt/lists/*': No such file or directory
   ```
3. command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

   output:

   ```
   E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ jammy: /usr/share/keyrings/winehq-archive.key != /usr/share/keyrings/winehq.gpg
   E: The list of sources could not be read.
   ```
4. On clicking Software and Updates, nothing opens.Please help.

---

Hi Romulo de Oliveira and Artur Meinild.
Here is the output of your suggested commands.

---

1. parag2tbubuntu@parag2TBubuntu-PC:~$ sudo rm /usr/share/keyrings/winehq.gpg

[sudo] password for parag2tbubuntu:

rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/keyrings/winehq.gpg': No such file or directory

2. parag2tbubuntu@parag2TBubuntu-PC:~$ sudo rm /usr/share/keyrings/winehq-archive.key

rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/keyrings/winehq-archive.key': No such file or directory

3. parag2tbubuntu@parag2TBubuntu-PC:~$ sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources

parag2tbubuntu@parag2TBubuntu-PC:~$

---

Please explain and guide me.

Comment: The WineHQ PPA you're using has nothing for your release, Ubuntu 22.04. And unless you actually need the very latest Wine version (extremely unlikely) then you better install the version already in the official repositories.

Comment: My question was -how to get rid of the error ? . . so that I can  reinstall Wine- whatever version. Even when I try to open Synaptic Package Manager the same error crops in and the package manager fails to open. Any assistance on this is welcome.

Comment: Remove that PPA to start with something.

Comment: Please tell me how to remove the PPA. The entry 'Wine' in Software is already gone.
Even when I try to open Synaptic Package Manager the same error crops in and the package manager fails to open.

Comment: The easy way is opening Software & Updates > Other software, click on it and remove.

Comment: I tried that. But there is no entry regarding Wine in that space. tried
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install Then ...
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get remove --dry-run package-name Then ...sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get clean package-name
sudo apt-get install --reinstall package-name Still I am getting the same error.

Comment: There must be one with  https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/

Comment: I tried as written in https://websetnet.net/how-to-fix-unmet-dependencies-error-on-ubuntu/ . But getting the same error. Please help.

Comment: Wrong! Again, the problem started when you added a PPA that has nothing to your release. You need to remove it, not trying to to solve UNSOLVABLE dependencies errors.

Comment: I have edited my question in order that the problem is better understood.

Comment: It's really hard to read your question, but it looks like you have a source file `winehq.list` that you should delete if you are trying to get rid of the ppa.

Comment: Organic Marble : Here is my System Info regarding Repos.
No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list 
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list 
           1: deb https: //dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/balena-etcher.list 
           1: deb https: //dl.cloudsmith.io/public/balena/etcher/deb/linuxmint una main
           2: deb-src https: //dl.cloudsmith.io/public/balena/etcher/deb/linuxmint una main.
System not allowing to delete. Error msg is same.See my comments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sudo apt-get... returns "Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source" error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1329308/sudo-apt-get-returns-conflicting-values-set-for-option-signed-by-regarding-s)

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo rm /usr/share/keyrings/winehq.gpg


sudo rm /usr/share/keyrings/winehq-archive.key


sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources
```

Comment: You should probably explain why removing those files is an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt policy | grep winehq

ls /usr/share/keyrings | grep winehq

sudo rm /usr/share/keyrings/winehq-archive-keyring.gpg

ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d | grep winehq

sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq.list

sudo apt update